# How to use an XML path file to save pictures

Tags: android, xml, path

I created a XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/myApp/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

Now, what I want to do is to use this folder to store pictures taken by my app, but I'm not sure how to make this the default folder to do so. I tried writing the folder as a File path, but that throws `IllegalArgumentException`, since that folder doesn't seem to exist yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it use to sharing purpose to hide actual path to others.

FileProvider is a special subclass of ContentProvider that facilitates secure sharing of files associated with an app by creating a content:// Uri for a file instead of a file:/// Uri.

You need to keep this file under xml directory.
res->xml-yourXmlName
You need to add meta-data in androidManifest.xml

```
<application>
    ...
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.mydomain.fileprovider"//(your projcet package name)
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
          android:resource="@xml/yourXmlName" />
    </provider>
    ...
</application>
```

Now you can use the path like this..

```
File imagePath = new File(Context.getFilesDir(), "Android/data/myApp/files/Pictures");
File newFile = new File(imagePath, "default_image.jpg");
Uri contentUri = getUriForFile(getContext(),   "your_project_package_name", newFile);
```

Output will be:

```
content://your_project_package_name/my_images/default_image.jpg
```

It will hide your hole path...
[For Details about it.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html)

Comment: Thanks! What and how should I use the Uri for?